# How to recode a vector in RStudio

Tags: r

I would like to recode numeric vectors.
All numeric vectors > 1 should be coded as 1. All vectors < 1 should be coded as 0.

Example:

```
X    Y
1    1029
2    0
3    12
4    -2
```

What I wish to receive:

```
X    Y
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `pmax`

```
pmax(sign(df$Y), 0)
#[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is named `df` then:

```
> ifelse(sign(df$y)<0, 0, sign(df$y))
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `dplyr` package and the use of `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(y = ifelse(y > 1, 1, 0))
```